# File conversion to DAT in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh

I would like to convert a file to .dat below is my query

I have a File eg: ABC this file doesn't have an extension(when i click its propertise it says type of file: file ) I want to convert this file to a .dat by writing a unix script

Comment: Run `mv ABC ABC.dat` in a terminal

Comment: mv fullpath/ABC ABC.dat should work, can you explain the problem.

Comment: it works now i get it so it moves and renames the file, perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux (and Unix) do not use the file extension to define the type of a file, though some programs to use the file extension as a guideline.  Unix/Linux examines the file magic number (the first bytes) of the file to determine the file type, though the program 'file' is the best explanation of how this is done (three tests, filesystem tests, magic tests, and language tests, the first that succeeds determines the file type).

Windows makes heavy use of the file extension to determine file type, and keeps metadata which maps file extension to application(s) which understand the file.

Linux/Unix uses the file magic number, examination of the first line of the file, and hints at the file type (for human use and some program use) using the file extension.

MacOS tracks file metadata using extension, file type code and creator code (metadata kept apart from filename), although OSX is derived from a Unix-like OS, so many of the Linux/Unix notes are applicable.